# Rhino 1.5 R5 not evaluating JavaScript correctly when finding array differences

Tags: javascript, arrays, rhino

I'm having a problem with some JavaScript which is being evaluated in an app using Rhino 1.5 R5 (Rhino 1.5 release 5 2004 03 25). I cannot update Rhino independently.

I have two arrays: the original data (pastedArr) and an array of only valid values (validatedArr) and I'm trying to find the difference (the "bad" values). I've found a function online to help (sym) and I've had to prototype forEach, but it works perfectly in jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/zr3abc0c/).

In app, using Rhino, it doesn't return elements which are integers (even though they are stored as strings), like the script below and in the fiddle link which returns ["33"] on jsfiddle but null in my application. If parameter0 was ["33","1A","ABC"] it would return only ["1A","ABC"] in app.

I can't figure out where it is failing with these "integer" string elements.

```js
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.18
// Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.18
if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {

  Array.prototype.forEach = function(callback, thisArg) {

    var T, k;

    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError(' this is null or not defined');
    }

    // 1. Let O be the result of calling toObject() passing the
    // |this| value as the argument.
    var O = Object(this);

    // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get() internal
    // method of O with the argument "length".
    // 3. Let len be toUint32(lenValue).
    var len = O.length >>> 0;

    // 4. If isCallable(callback) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
    // See: http://es5.github.com/#x9.11
    if (typeof callback !== "function") {
      throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
    }

    // 5. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let
    // T be undefined.
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      T = thisArg;
    }

    // 6. Let k be 0
    k = 0;

    // 7. Repeat, while k < len
    while (k < len) {

      var kValue;

      // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
      //    This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
      // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the HasProperty
      //    internal method of O with argument Pk.
      //    This step can be combined with c
      // c. If kPresent is true, then
      if (k in O) {

        // i. Let kValue be the result of calling the Get internal
        // method of O with argument Pk.
        kValue = O[k];

        // ii. Call the Call internal method of callback with T as
        // the this value and argument list containing kValue, k, and O.
        callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);
      }
      // d. Increase k by 1.
      k++;
    }
    // 8. return undefined
  };
}

function sym( /* pass one or more arrays here */ ) {
  var ans = [],
    cnts = {},
    currentMap;

  //count all items in the array
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    currentMap = {};
    arguments[i].forEach(function(item) {
      // if we haven't already counted this item in this array
      if (!currentMap.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
        if (cnts.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
          // increase cnt
          ++cnts[item].cnt;
        } else {
          // initalize cnt and value
          cnts[item] = {
            cnt: 1,
            val: item
          };
        }
      }
      // keep track of whethere we've already counted this item in this array
      currentMap[item] = true;
    });
  }
  // output all items that have a cnt of 1
  for (var item in cnts) {
    if (cnts.hasOwnProperty(item) && cnts[item].cnt === 1) {
      ans.push(cnts[item].val);
    }
  }

  return ans;
}

function sort_uniq_fast(a) {
  var seen = {};
  var out = [];
  var len = a.length;
  var j = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var item = a[i];
    if (seen[item] !== 1) {
      seen[item] = 1;
      out[j++] = item;
    }
  }
  return out.sort();
}

function getBadCodes(pastedArr, validatedArr) {
  var result = sym(pastedArr, validatedArr);
  return sort_uniq_fast(result);
}

   var parameter0 = ["33"];
   var parameter1 = new Array();

alert(getBadCodes(parameter0,parameter1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Rhino 1.5R5 lying around, but Rhino treats integer properties as special, because of their use in Array. I am speculating that there is a bug in this handling in Rhino 1.5R5.

I would suggest preprocessing the items to compare and postprocessing the result, as I do in this answer (see prefix and unprefix).

Let us know whether it works! (And I'll update the answer accordingly.)

```js
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.18
// Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.18
if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {

  Array.prototype.forEach = function(callback, thisArg) {

    var T, k;

    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError(' this is null or not defined');
    }

    // 1. Let O be the result of calling toObject() passing the
    // |this| value as the argument.
    var O = Object(this);

    // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get() internal
    // method of O with the argument "length".
    // 3. Let len be toUint32(lenValue).
    var len = O.length >>> 0;

    // 4. If isCallable(callback) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
    // See: http://es5.github.com/#x9.11
    if (typeof callback !== "function") {
      throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
    }

    // 5. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let
    // T be undefined.
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      T = thisArg;
    }

    // 6. Let k be 0
    k = 0;

    // 7. Repeat, while k < len
    while (k < len) {

      var kValue;

      // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
      //    This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
      // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the HasProperty
      //    internal method of O with argument Pk.
      //    This step can be combined with c
      // c. If kPresent is true, then
      if (k in O) {

        // i. Let kValue be the result of calling the Get internal
        // method of O with argument Pk.
        kValue = O[k];

        // ii. Call the Call internal method of callback with T as
        // the this value and argument list containing kValue, k, and O.
        callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);
      }
      // d. Increase k by 1.
      k++;
    }
    // 8. return undefined
  };
}

function sym( /* pass one or more arrays here */ ) {
  var ans = [],
    cnts = {},
    currentMap;

  //count all items in the array
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    currentMap = {};
    arguments[i].forEach(function(item) {
      // if we haven't already counted this item in this array
      if (!currentMap.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
        if (cnts.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
          // increase cnt
          ++cnts[item].cnt;
        } else {
          // initalize cnt and value
          cnts[item] = {
            cnt: 1,
            val: item
          };
        }
      }
      // keep track of whethere we've already counted this item in this array
      currentMap[item] = true;
    });
  }
  // output all items that have a cnt of 1
  for (var item in cnts) {
    if (cnts.hasOwnProperty(item) && cnts[item].cnt === 1) {
      ans.push(cnts[item].val);
    }
  }

  return ans;
}

function sort_uniq_fast(a) {
  var seen = {};
  var out = [];
  var len = a.length;
  var j = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var item = a[i];
    if (seen[item] !== 1) {
      seen[item] = 1;
      out[j++] = item;
    }
  }
  return out.sort();
}

function prefix(array) {
    var rv = [];
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
      rv[i] = "A" + array[i];
    }
    return rv;
}

function unprefix(array) {
    var rv = [];
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
      rv[i] = array[i].substring(1);
    }
    return rv;
}

function getBadCodes(pastedArr, validatedArr) {
  var result = unprefix(sym(prefix(pastedArr), prefix(validatedArr)));
  return sort_uniq_fast(result);
}

   var parameter0 = ["33"];
   var parameter1 = new Array();

alert(getBadCodes(parameter0,parameter1));
```

Comment: This does work and solves the stated issue, however it exposes another problem. 

    var parameter0 = [null,"1a","33","33-D-1A"];
    var parameter1 = ["33-D-1A"];

this would return ["1a","33",null] now it returns ["1a","33","null"] which displays "null" to the interface/user

Comment: @david-p-caldwell I just added an if clause to your prefix function

`function prefix(array) {
  var rv = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] !== null) {
      rv[i] = "A" + array[i];
    }
  }
  return rv;
}`

Comment: Yeah, the stated approach won't work for "null." What would be the "correct" handling of null for your case?

Comment: Ah, crossed comments. Glad you got it figured out!